# How to test RabbitMQ producer using mocha and sinon?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have amqp producer.

```js
//rmq.producer.js

module.exports.rmqPublisher = function (message) {
  amqp.connect(process.env.RMQ_URL, function (error0, connection) {
    if (error0) {
      throw error0;
    }
    connection.createChannel(function (error1, channel) {
      if (error1) {
        throw error1;
      }
      var exchange = "web_chat_topic";
      var key = "web_chat.route_key";
      var msg = JSON.stringify(message);

      channel.assertExchange(exchange, "topic", {
        durable: false,
      });

      channel.publish(exchange, key, Buffer.from(msg));
      logger.info(
        `Message has been published to RMQ exchange: ${exchange}, key: ${key}`
      );
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
      connection.close();
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

I publish a message to the exchange topic by calling `rmqPublisher("some_message..")`

Now, I want to test this using mocha + sinon in nodeJS,

I have writtern following test file

```js
var producer = require("../rmq.producer")

var sinon = require("sinon");
var assert = sinon.assert;

var producerTest = function () {
  it("producer connection - success test", async function () {
    producer.rmqPublisher("fake_msg");
  });
  afterEach(function () {
    sinon.verifyAndRestore();
  });
};

describe("test_producer", producerTest);
```

With the above test, it is able to cover all lines except the error handling part.

Could anyone please help me to write the tests to cover all lines?

Thanks!

Comment: What package are you using for amqp?

Comment: I am using amqplib